# equivalent CURL for Lua, (Django API Json to Lua Json) POST method

Tags: json, curl, lua, coronasdk, django-piston

I have a Django that having API for JSON, and I want it to get it in my Lua (Corona SDK) project.

if I `CURL` my Django project.

```
curl -l -X POST -d "message=getstrings" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getstrings/
```

this will return:

```
{
    "message": "Something good happened on the server!", 
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "003", 
            "doc1": "sd.doc", 
            "title": "Test", 
            "artist": "ABBA", 
            "img": "sd.png", 
            "genre": "Pop"
        }, 
        {
            "code": "004", 
            "doc1": "sdsd.doc", 
            "title": "sdf", 
            "artist": "ABBA", 
            "img": "sdsd.png", 
            "genre": "Pop"
        }
    ], 
    "success": true
}
```

i have a problem in `post method` for `json` in `Lua`. i want the returned json will be get in Lua.

i try this in my `Lua`.

```
local response = {}
local r, c, h = http.request{
  url= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getstrings/",
  method = "POST",
  headers = {
    ["content-length"] = "",
    ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  source = ltn12.source.string(post),
  sink = ltn12.sink.table(response)

}
local path = system.pathForFile("r.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory)
local file = io.open (path, "w")

file:write (response[1] .. "\n")
io.close (file)
```

when i open `r.txt`:

i got this ...

```
File "home/myhome/workspace/djangoproj/api/handlers.py", line 21, in create
  if attrs['message'] == 'getstrings':

KeyError: 'message'
```

i know what cause of the error because `message` and its value did not passed by Lua.
my question is that what is the equivalent code like this CURL

```
curl -l -X POST -d "message=getstrings" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getstrings/
```

in Lua (Corona SDK) so that the Lua can get and download the returned `Json`? is my code in my `Lua` is correct?

do anyone have an idea about my case?
thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the network.request function provided by Corona?
It is asynchronous as well.

```
local function listener(event)
    print(event.response)
    print(event.isError)
    print(event.status)
end


local url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getstrings/"

local body = "message=getstrings"

local headers = {}
headers["content-length"] = body:len(),
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"



local postData = {}
postData.body = body
postData.headers = headers

network.request(url,"POST",listener,postData)
```

Have a read here
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/networkrequest

**EDIT**

If you REALLY want to use http.request then you can do this.

```
local url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getstrings/"
local body = "message=getstrings"
local headers = {
    ["content-length"] = body:len(),
    ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }

local response = {}
local r, c, h = http.request{
  url= url,
  method = "POST",
  headers = headers,
  source = ltn12.source.string(body),
  sink = ltn12.sink.table(response)

}
```

Comment: thanks SatheeshJM for the answer... in the `print(event.response),print(event.isError),print(event.status)` i got this out-put. for `event.isError` = `true`, `event.response` = '' and `event.status` = `nil` ? why did i get `error`?

Comment: Well! I'm not sure. According to the docs
`event.isError: A boolean value: true in the case of a network error, false otherwise. As of build 2012.744, "event.isError" only returns true if we failed to connect to the server or upon response timeout`

Comment: Did you set the content length correctly?
`headers["content-length"] = body:len()` and not 
`headers["content-length"] = ""`

I have updated my answer now